# Line with Negative Slope closed in $\Bbb{R}^2_\ell$.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that $L=\{(x,-x) \mid x \in \Bbb{R} \}$ as a subspace of the product space $\Bbb{R}_\ell^2$ is closed, where each factor is endowed with the lower limit topology.

First I thought that $L$ is homeomorphic to the diagonal, which is closed since $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ is Hausdorff, with $f(x,-x) = (x,x)$ being the homeomorphism; but this isn't continuous. I then supposed that $(x,y)$, where WLOG $y < -x$, is a limit point of $L$ and tried finding an open nhbd of $(x,y)$ that would cause problems. Finally, I tried to show 
$$\Bbb{R}^2_\ell - L = \{(x,y) \mid y < -x \} \cup \{(x,y) \mid y > -x \} = P_1 \cup P_2$$
 is open. I thought perhaps $P_1$ and $P_2$ are homeomorphic, where $P_2$ is obviously open (if $(x,y) \in P_2$, then $[x,\infty) \times [y,\infty) \subseteq P_2$); I tried showing the function $f(x,y) = (-x,-y)$ is a homeomorphism between $P_2$ and $P_1$, but this isn't continuous either. It seems the only recourse I have is to show $P_1$ is open. After having drawn many pictures, I still can't see how I am to fit an open nbbd around $(x,y) \in P_1$ that doesn't intersect the line $L$.

Comment: The lower limit topology is finer than the Euclidean topology. Hence $\operatorname{id} \colon \mathbb{R}_{\ell}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: look for the straight line (let's call it $L'$) through $(x,y)$ but orthogonal to $L$. The "square" formed by $(x,y)$ and any point on $L'$ that lies in between $(x,y)$ and $L$ will do. You could for example take that point to be $L' \cap L$.